# React Navigation: TabNavigator: How to get a callback on swipe event or in-between transitioning state from one tab to the other?

Tags: react-navigation, tabnavigator, react-native-tabnavigator

Basically I need to animate the custom `tabBarComponent` when user is **swiping** the `TabNavigator` screens (**Tinder-like**).

But not able to fire that in-between event where animation **logic** can be written.

Any pointers will be helpful.